# How to extract a Jira Id from a GitHub squashed commit message using bash regex, sed, grep or groovy?

Tags: regex, bash, groovy, sed, grep

I would like to extract a Jira Id from a commit message string resulted from squash-merging a GitHub PR.  If multiple Jira Ids are present, I would like to extract the first one.

How to do it using bash regex, sed, grep, groovy, or any other available comman line tools?

Test cases:

```
ABCD-1231 dummy title XYZ-566 (#423)
=> ABCD-1231

[ABCD-1232, XYZ-566] dummy title (#424)
=> ABCD-1232

[ABCD-1233] dummy title (#425)
=> ABCD-1233

ABCD-1234: dummy title (#426)
=> ABCD-1234

XYZ-567 dummy title (#427)
=> XYZ-567

(XYZ-568) dummy title (#428)
=> XYZ-568

"XYZ-569" dummy title (#429)
=> XYZ-569

dummy title XYZ-570 dummy title (#430)
=> XYZ-570

DUMMY title XYZ-571 dummy title (#431)
=> XYZ-571

'feature/XYZ-572' dummy title (#432)
=> XYZ-572

FEATURE|XYZ-573 dummy title (#433)
=> XYZ-573

<Feature\XYZ-574> dummy title (#434)
=> XYZ-574

dummy title FAKE-XYZ-575 dummy title (#435)
=> <nothing>

dummy title abcdXYZ-576 dummy title (#436)
=> <nothing>
```

In **Bash**,

`"[^A-Z]*(([A-Z]+-[0-9]+)*.*) \(#([0-9]+)\)"`
would fail

- "FEATURE|XYZ-573 dummy title (#433)"
- "[Feature\XYZ-574] dummy title (#434)"
- ...

and negative lookbehind such as the following seems not supported by bash: `".*[^A-Z]*((?<!([A-Z]+)-?)[A-Z]+-[0-9]+).*"`

Can anyone suggest a solution, or the right tool to do this task?

Comment: Your examples are helpful, but as a start, I would specify an exact description of how such a commit msg may look like, which characters are allowed in the respective parts of the line, and the rule how to find your Jira-ID in it.

Comment: Any script you try to write will fail at times unless you can define in what way "dummy title" must be different from the strings you want to output. If the real string represented in your examples by "dummy title" just happened to be "XYZ-567" then how could you tell that was a "dummy title" instead of a  "Jira ID"?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to enable the *PCRE* engine on `grep` with the `-P`
option. This might depend on the version of `grep` you have on the
server. It will let you use lookarounds.

You can also limit the matching lines with the `-m 1` option, but it
won't help us a lot as the commit messages are on one line. I'll use
it just in case your commit message is on several lines. This can
save a few CPU cycles.

The `-o` option will only **o**utput the matches. We can then pass
the output to `head` in order to only take the first match.

For the pattern, I would try it with `(?<=^|[^\w-])[A-Z]+-\d+`.
I've used a positive lookbehind to match either the beginning of
the line or any char not being a word or a hyphen.

I tested all your commit messages in the following bash script :

```bash
#!/bin/bash

commits=(
    "ABCD-1231 dummy title XYZ-566 (#423)"
    "[ABCD-1232, XYZ-566] dummy title (#424)"
    "[ABCD-1233] dummy title (#425)"
    "ABCD-1234: dummy title (#426)"
    "XYZ-567 dummy title (#427)"
    "(XYZ-568) dummy title (#428)"
    '"XYZ-569" dummy title (#429)'
    "dummy title XYZ-570 dummy title (#430)"
    "DUMMY title XYZ-571 dummy title (#431)"
    "'feature/XYZ-572' dummy title (#432)"
    "FEATURE|XYZ-573 dummy title (#433)"
    "<Feature\XYZ-574> dummy title (#434)"
    "dummy title FAKE-XYZ-575 dummy title (#435)"
    "dummy title abcdXYZ-576 dummy title (#436)"
)

for (( i=0; i<${#commits[@]}; i++ ))
do
    echo ${commits[$i]}
    # A) My first attempt, using head to only get the first match.
    echo ${commits[$i]} | grep -P -m 1 -o '(?<=^|[^\w-])[A-Z]+-\d+' | head -n1

    # B) InSync's more sofisticated solution to match only the first
    # occurrence with the help of \K, which resets the starting point
    # of the reported match. This is a good way to consume characters
    # which we don't want in the output. It's also used because we can't
    # solve this with a positive lookbehind as the latter has to be a fixed
    # length pattern (not the case because of the ungreedy .*? pattern).
    # My positive lookbehind (?<=^|[^\w-]) can also be replaced by a
    # shorter negative lookbehind (?<![\w-])
    echo ${commits[$i]} | grep -P -m 1 -o '^.*?\K(?<![\w-])[A-Z]+-\d+'
done
```

#### EDIT

Thank you, @InSync, for your clever solution not using `head` and
by using *PCRE*'s `\K` pattern to reset the starting point of the
reported match. It's used to consume, in an ungreedy way, all the
characters before the first Jira Id. I've added it to the batch
above under the B) point.

Output, both A) and B) :

```
ABCD-1231 dummy title XYZ-566 (#423)
ABCD-1231
ABCD-1231
[ABCD-1232, XYZ-566] dummy title (#424)
ABCD-1232
ABCD-1232
[ABCD-1233] dummy title (#425)
ABCD-1233
ABCD-1233
ABCD-1234: dummy title (#426)
ABCD-1234
ABCD-1234
XYZ-567 dummy title (#427)
XYZ-567
XYZ-567
(XYZ-568) dummy title (#428)
XYZ-568
XYZ-568
"XYZ-569" dummy title (#429)
XYZ-569
XYZ-569
dummy title XYZ-570 dummy title (#430)
XYZ-570
XYZ-570
DUMMY title XYZ-571 dummy title (#431)
XYZ-571
XYZ-571
'feature/XYZ-572' dummy title (#432)
XYZ-572
XYZ-572
FEATURE|XYZ-573 dummy title (#433)
XYZ-573
XYZ-573
<Feature\XYZ-574> dummy title (#434)
XYZ-574
XYZ-574
dummy title FAKE-XYZ-575 dummy title (#435)
dummy title abcdXYZ-576 dummy title (#436)
```

Comment: `(?<=^|[^\w-])` can be simplified as [`(?<![\w-])`](https://regex101.com/r/327fOy/1).

Comment: Thanks a lot @InSync! Very good suggestion of simplification! I've added it to the answer. I left both solutions, as the `\K` might feel a bit more complicated for some less advanced persons.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!  Inspired by your answer, now I can also extract the PR number (e.g., "433") with ```grep -oP -m 1 '^.+?\(#\K\d+(?=\))```, and the description prior to the PR number part with ```grep -oP -m 1 '^.+?(?=$| \(#\d+\))'```.

Comment: @P.Luo Great! Glad you managed to solve your problem completely!